# Autosys job should be in success state even if the command job fails

Tags: shell, autosys

I am trying to run a job in autosys. However I am unable to implement the job in a such a way that even when command job fails autosys job should be success

I am trying to shell script using exitcode 99. However I am unable to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the attribute "max_exit_success" in the job definition (JIL) and set to values of exit code which you want to be considered as SUCCESS.